# C# method second parameter optional

Tags: c#, parameters, option-type

I am a newbie for C#.

current incomplete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classObjectMethodBasic
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number for first number to do a math on: ");
            int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Input a number for second number to do a math on or you need not enter one: ");
            int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int result1 = new int();
            result1 = Math.math(number1, number2);

            Console.WriteLine("Math result: " + result1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Math
    {
        public static int math(int number1, int number2 = 3)
        {
            int result1 = number1 + number2;
            return result1;
        }
    }
}
```

Need to make the second parameter (number2) optional.
In the current code, if I run it but don't enter a value for int number2 (means just hit enter), the program quits with exception which makes sense.
Exception error:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

How could I make the program work with the second parameter as optional?

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: When you hit enter without any input `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` fails to convert blank input to integer. You should first store value of `Console.ReadLine()` to some string value and check if is it no Null or empty. If it is null or empty you should call the method with only first number, else you try to convert that to integer and call method with two parameters.

Comment: I am not getting an exception when I remove `number2` from Math.math call. Can you include the code that throws the exception, please?

Comment: Your exception has nothing to do with the optional _parameter_. You've done that fine. However, you're blindly using `Convert.ToInt32()` on unvalidated input. If your `Console.ReadLine()` returns a non-numeric string value (including but not limited to an empty string), you'll end up with an exception. You need to save the result of your `ReadLine()`. If it's blank, you'll want to use your default parameter. If it's not blank, you should use `Int32.TryParse()`. If the `TryParse()` fails,  your user has entered something that's not a number, and should be alerted as such.

Comment: Nathan, the code I posted it is all, and it fails. thanks.
If I remove number 2 from Math.math call, it still fails.

Comment: J H, I presumed that you were entering a valid integer for both inputs, but my presumption was incorrect apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your code around to validate the input it received would be better overall. In your case you are probably not entering a value for the second value see the corrections below

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input a number for first number to do a math on: ");
        int number1 = 0;
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!Int32.TryParse(input1, out number1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1 was entered incorrectly");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Input a number for second number to do a math on or you need not enter one: ");
        int number2 = 0;
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();


        if (input2.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Math result: " + Math.math(number1));
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(input2, out number2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number 2 was entered incorrectly");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Math result: " + Math.math(number1, number2));
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: although for debug purposes i'd, **personally**, always set the `readline` outside of passing as param. thankfully, you show how to handle garbage user input.

Comment: I would normally also follow that pattern you describe, but for this code, I was focused on other parts, and copy/pasted that part.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input.
To clarify my intention of the specific task further, it was not to force a user to input a valid value for 1st or 2nd parameter, but if the user doesn't enter 2nd parameter, the default value int '3' is used instead so that the code can still run without exception.

Comment: I will adjust the code to continue execution for string.Empty, but fail for non-numeric non-empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You have already declared the second parameter as optional. The error is due to this line of code:

```
 int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Either you can modify your code to check for both the parameters before calling the `Math.math()` function or pass both the parameters like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classObjectMethodBasic
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number for first number to do a math on: ");
            string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int number1 = 0;
            int.TryParse(input1, out number1);

            Console.WriteLine("Input a number for second number to do a math on or you need not enter one: ");
            string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int number2 = 0;
            int.TryParse(input2, out number2);

            int result1 = new int();
            result1 = Math.math(number1, number2);

            Console.WriteLine("Math result: " + result1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Math
    {
        public static int math(int number1, int number2 = 3)
        {
            int result1 = number1 + number2;
            return result1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can give false results. if user enters 'alphabet' and '10', output will be 10. if non-numeric, error needs reported to user.

Comment: Agreed but the op wants the solution about the exception not the complete refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input.
If I don't enter a value for 2nd parameter, the value '0' seems always used, what if I would like the default '3' to be used?